# distribution of linearly transformed variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable and it takes values from $\ell_{2}$, which is the space of square-summable sequences. Next, let us define random variable $U=a(X - b)$, for some $a \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $b \in \ell_{2}$, also both $a$ and $b$ are not all zeros.

Next, assume that for some random variables $V$ and $Y$, taking values from $\ell_{2}$, defined on, possibly, another probability space we know that $V = a(Y - b)$ and $V\stackrel{d}{=}U$.

Does this mean that

$$
Y\stackrel{d}{=}X
$$
?

Does the result depend on the space which the variables take values from?

Comment: What do you mean by $a(X-b)$? Is it an inner product?

Comment: Yes, $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution, and no, the result does not depend on the space which the variables take values from. It follows immediately from the definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#:~:text=is%20given%20below.-,Equality%20in%20distribution,on%20the%20same%20probability%20space.

Comment: Dear @MohammadKhosravi, it was a mistake. $a$ is just a positive number. Thank you!

Comment: Dear @Arash , you can try to write it as an answer and then it will be more clear what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @LrM I did actually. It started to get votes to be deleted, so I deleted it myself. Maybe because of a bounty on it, I don't know. All I was trying to say was that I am confident you can figure it out on your own by following the definition. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that the result is dependent on which spaces we define things.

I believe we can even prove a more general result than what you are looking for. Let $\varphi$ be a measurable transformation and define $U = \varphi (X)$ and $V = \varphi(Y)$ and assume that $U \overset{d}{=} V$. For a measurable set $B$ we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_{U}(B) &= \mathbb{P}_{\varphi (X)}(B) = \mathbb{P}(X \in \varphi^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}_{X}(\varphi^{-1}(B)) \\
\mathbb{P}_{V}(B) &= \mathbb{P}_{\varphi (Y)}(B) = \mathbb{P}(Y \in \varphi^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}_{Y}(\varphi^{-1}(B))
\end{align*}
So we may conclude that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_{X}(\varphi^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}_{Y}(\varphi^{-1}(B))
\end{align*}
Implying that $\mathbb{P}_{X} = \mathbb{P}_{Y}$, meaning $X\overset{d}{=}Y$.

Comment: aren’t we implicitly assuming $\varphi$ to be surjective? I guess we need that to prove equality in distribution between $X$ and $Y$ at each measurable set.

Comment: I think I see your point, but since $\varphi$ is any measurable function, wouldn't the measures be equal, as this encompasses surjective functions?

Comment: indeed, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n,\ldots)$, where $X_i$ are scalar random variables, similarly for $U$, $V$, $Y$ and $a$, $b$.

Then it follows immediately with

$$P(Y_1\le y_1, \ldots, Y_n \le y_n,\ldots)$$
$$=P(\frac 1a V_1 + b_1 \le y_1,\ldots,\frac 1a V_n + b_n \le y_n,\ldots)$$
$$=P(V_1 \le a(y_1-b_1),\ldots, V_n \le a(y_n-b_n),\ldots)$$
$$=P(U_1 \le a(y_1-b_1),\ldots, U_n \le a(y_n-b_n),\ldots)$$
$$=P(\frac 1a U_1 + b_1 \le y_1,\ldots,\frac 1a U_n + b_n \le y_n,\ldots)$$
$$=P(X_1\le y_1, \ldots, X_n \le y_n,\ldots)$$

Hence the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the same.